# How to use a variable concatenated with a string in dbt_utils.dateadd in dbt?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have set a variable called year.
I want to use dateadd function but instead of using the from_date_or_timestamp like the following example

```
{{ dbt_utils.dateadd(datepart='day', interval=1, from_date_or_timestamp="'2017-01-01'") }}
```

I want to use the variable year concatenated with the month and the day, something like this

```
{{ dbt_utils.dateadd(datepart='day', interval=1, from_date_or_timestamp= year ~ '-01-01') }}
```

But I can't get this to work... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

A workaround to this could be the following:

```sql
{% set year = 2021 %}

select 
  {{ dbt_utils.dateadd(
    datepart = 'day',
    interval = 1,
    from_date_or_timestamp = "'" ~ year ~ "-01-01'"
    )
  }} as date_add_field
```

Since you need the input of `from_date_or_timestamp` to be a string, adding a trailing `'` and then `-01-01'`, both wrapped in `""`, you will make it work. The compiled SQL will look like the following (I am using Snowflake, your compiled SQL might defer):

```sql
select 
  dateadd(day, 1, '2021-01-01') as date_add_field
```